# Sample enterprise application for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I understand there are a number of small applications built on MVC. Is there an enterprise application sample that is standardized and uses best practices?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662150/would-you-use-the-sarp-architecture-in-a-new-commercial-project/1977397#1977397).

Answer (score 2):

http://sharparchitecture.net/ is pretty good

Comment: It is good, but it's not really an enterprise application sample, so it doesn't quite answer the question. It's a pretty useful toolkit; the Northwind sample included in the source might be a good demonstration of the conventions of the toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

When I was getting familiar with MVC, I used the Orchard CMS project to pick up the tricks of the trade.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's a good example of how to waste 90% of your effort building a bloated infrastructure around an anemic domain. I don't recommend it.